# How can I ignore Lorem Ipsum text from my Spellchecker?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) and I was wondering if it was possible to ignore Lorem Ipsum text from being marked as as "unknown word" without having to add every single word in my `"cSpell.userWords"` list.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open VSCode settings.
2. Search for `cSpell.language`.
3. Add `lorem` to the list.

[image: CSpell lorem]

Answer (score 4):

You only need to disable/enable the spell checker by adding comments as shown in the illustrations below. This was how I did it for HTML:

`<!--cSpell:disable -->`

before the latin paragraph, and then

```
<!--cSpell:enable -->
```

afterwards.

Use the commenting syntax for the language you are coding in.

With cSpell enabled:
[image: with cSpell enabled (default)]

With cSpell disabled:
[image: with cSpell disabled]

Comment: I originally voted down as I didn't read properly, this is a viable way to get cspell to ignore specific blocks - perhaps you can alter you're answer so that at the very start it says something like "You can tell CSpell to ignore specific blocks by surrounding them with this markup." Perhaps that might make the information a bit easier to absorb

Comment: One probably can use this technic to disable spell checking in *almost* any file. For instance to disable spell checking in a sample data TypeScript file I use a string `// cSpell: disable` in the beginning of the file. As you can see I have to use line comment syntax but as long as I can see cSpell searches just for string `cSpell: disable`.